# Django mod_wsgi: Exception occurred processing wsgi script

Tags: python, django, deployment, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django project and facing this error.

My project structure like below:

```
my_project
   my_project
      urls.py
      settings.py
      index.wsgi
      home
         views.py
         models.py
         .........

    requirements.txt
    manage.py
```

And my index.wsgi looks like below:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/my_project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/uni/my_project')
sys.path.append('/var/www/uni/my_project/home')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/user/.virtualenvs/my_project/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And in my virtualhost, the configuration is like below :

```
    <Directory /var/www/uni/my_project/templates/static>
        Allow from all
     </Directory>  
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/uni/news/my_project/my_project/index.wsgi
```

The apache error.log is shown as:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=27330): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/uni/my_project/my_project/index.wsgi'.
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]     self.load_middleware()
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]     for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]     self._setup()
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip]     raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
[Mon Jun 09 14:23:53 2014] [error] [client ip] ImportError: Could not import settings 'my_project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named my_project.settings
```

I went through the mod_wsgi and djnago docs. I know the project structure is not maintaining all the best practices. I will change it later but before that I need to go it live.

I tried by changing file permissions and all the changes that mentioned in same questions.

So, I am assuming I am doing something wrong.

Where is the mis configuration in the above files?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show the errors from the Apache log.

Comment: added apache error log

Comment: @DanielRoseman any idea? I have added the log.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file to make `my_project` a package?

Comment: Is there is an __init__.py

Answer (score 5):

I have a checklist in these kind of scenarios:

1. Execute a script testing the `index.wsgi` interface directly with python, correct errors until the output shows that all is ok. (see update)
2. Check for permissions.
3. Check for apache configuration.

**Update:**

Executing `python my_project/index.wsgi` directly shows nothing in console, this approach works on fcgi configuration but no in wsgi, you will need a script that create a test server and show posible errors on console, the example script is this:

**test_server.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from wsgiref.util import setup_testing_defaults
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from my_project.index import application #importing the project's index.wsgi file
httpd = make_server('', 8000, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Steps:

- Run the test in console (even local)
- Go to the browser and navigate to this server:port
- see the logs in console

**Recommendations:**

1. Check for you `__init__.py` either in the project folder and the settings folder
2. Try to use *relative paths* in the settings **and in the .wsgi file** (see example)
3. Verify the uppercase/lowecase in your names (probably changing `"MY_PROJECT.settings"` for `"my_project.settings"`

example:

```
import os, sys, site

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
WORK_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIRECTORY, '..')

#Add the site-packages
site.addsitedir('/home/SERVER_USERNAME/.virtualenvs/histology_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

#activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/histology_env/bin/activate_this.py")
#execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

#adding the project to the python path
sys.path.append(WORK_DIRECTORY)
#adding the parent directory to the python path
sys.path.append(os.path.join(WORK_DIRECTORY, '..'))

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: 1. show nothing 2. permissions are ok 3.which configuration you are referring?

Comment: My fault, the 1 point works only if you have the fcgi configuration, you can change -for test- to fcgi ans test in console, i will edit the answer adding a script for test a wsgi script.

I the 3 point (if both 1 and 2 passed) you have to check the virtualhost configuration, the .htaccess configuration and at least the wsgi module (is less probable)

Comment: What is this `index.wsgi interface` you speak of?

Comment: It's the python script that serves as a bridge between the django project and the wsgi (Apache) server it's placed in the django project folder

Answer (score 3):

I had this same thing happen to me a few days ago. I was reading all about it but this is how I finally fixed it all.

1. Your django wsgi file should be a python file (wsgi.py), not an
   index file (index.wsgi). This is what mine looked like, obviously replace usernames and folders.

   ```
   import os, sys, site

   #Add the site-packages
   site.addsitedir('/home/SERVER_USERNAME/.virtualenvs/histology_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages')


   #activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/histology_env/bin/activate_this.py")
   #execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

   sys.path.append('/opt/')
   sys.path.append('/opt/MY_PROJECT')
   sys.path.append('/opt/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT')
   os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MY_PROJECT.settings")

   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   application = get_wsgi_application()
   ```
2. DON"T ADD THE PROJECT TO THE /var/www/html/ FOLDER! I didn't realize that was a problem until where I got to you are. I chose to put it into the /opt/ directory.
3. You don't need to activate the env to get this to work. You add the packages in the first line. This is why I have it commented out in mine (site works fine).
4. In the virtual configuration

   ```
   NameVirtualHost *:80
   WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
   WSGIPythonPath /home/SERVER_USERNAME/.virtualenvs/histology_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
   <VirtualHost *:80>

           WSGIDaemonProcess safe python-path=/opt/virtual_microscope:/home/SERVER_USERNAME/.virtualenvs/histology_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
           WSGIProcessGroup safe
           WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/wsgi.py

           Alias /static/ /var/www/html/home/static/
           Alias /slides/ /var/www/html/pictures/slides/

           <Directory /opt/MY_PROJECT/MY_PROJECT/>
                   Order deny,allow
                   Allow from all
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. After you change these settings in the host file, make sure you `sudo service httpd reload`

Good luck, I know what you're going through and it is frustrating to not have the answers. Hope this works for you, it did for me.

Comment: Why not add it to the /var/www/html folder?  I have mine added there but my problem is completely different.  And if you don't add it there, why are media and static still in that directory?  Could I just move everything to the  /opt directory and change my aliases?  Why is it even a problem at all?

Comment: Providing the python path "WSGIPythonPath" on top of .conf file worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be specifying the virtualenv for the project in your Apache config, not your application WSGI file. Since you're using Apache, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv for what you need to put into your Apache configuration. I would also highly recommend running in daemon mode - unless you have a very good reason not to, you should almost always be using daemon mode on Apache.

Then reset your project WSGI file to

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```